# see a part of bigger canvas on a small canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a big canvas of 1377x740px, and other canvas with dimmensions 200x200.
this last canvas is used a mode of preview, of object selected in a dropdown list. when i select the name of the object, the object need to appear in the small canvas, with the same proportions.

My question is, how can i do this?

I have a code, but this code, fit the object to a width and height of the small canvas,

```
obj.set({
            scaleY:  obj.height / (obj.getBoundingRect().height),
            scaleX:   obj.width / (obj.getBoundingRect().width),

        });
```

This not works,
I want something like: this [fit-object-css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Cik.png)

like the box "contain" of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Sloved with this code:

```
var BR = obj.getBoundingRect();
        if(BR.width>canvas2.width){
            while(BR.width+50>canvas2.width){
                canvas2.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas2.getCenter().top, canvas2.getCenter().left), canvas2.getZoom()/1.2);
                BR=obj.getBoundingRect();
            }
        }
        if(BR.width+3<canvas2.width){
            while(BR.width+50<canvas2.width){
                canvas2.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas2.getCenter().top, canvas2.getCenter().left), canvas2.getZoom()*1.2);
                BR=obj.getBoundingRect();
            }
        }
        if(BR.height>canvas2.height){
            while(BR.height>canvas2.height){
                canvas2.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas2.getCenter().top, canvas2.getCenter().left), canvas2.getZoom()/1.2);
                BR=obj.getBoundingRect();
            }
        }
```